# Show value of one table in other table (Codeigniter 4)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two tables:

table1:

| ID | Name | Email | profile_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

table2:

| id | profile_name |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

I display `table` to the user on the website in the view using a `foreach` loop, but in that view I want the `profile_id` to display the corresponding `profile_name` from `table2` and not the id.

I think I'm supposed to use `join()`, but I have no clue how to use this. I can provide my code if neccesairy but I don't think it is.

Any help?

Comment: _"I think I'm supposed to use join(), but I have no clue how to use this"_ - Then it's a perfect opportunity to do some [proper research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) into the subject. But yes, using `join` would be the correct way of solving this.

Comment: You definitely should provide the code.

Comment: My problem was solved without it, I just didn't bother because I didn't know what to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before looking up the codeigniter 4 way of creating queries, take a moment to understand the basic SQL behind joins. Joins allow you to combine results from multiple tables. You need to be specific about which table you want which value from. In basic SQL it looks like

```
SELECT table1.something, table2.somethingElse 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.referenceID
```

The key is the `ON` keyword. It establishes the link between the 2 tables. Sometimes you will have the same field names in your result, like ID, so you can change those in your query using `AS` like

```
SELECT  
   *, table1.id AS table1_id, 
   table2.id AS table2_id 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id= table2.referenceID
```

This query will still get the id column from both databases, but will also get the new ad-hoc fields so we can differentiate in the result.

In [codeigniter 4](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) you just use their method

```
$builder = $db->table('table1');
$builder->select('table1.*, table2.profile_name');
$builder->join('table2', 'table1.profile_id = table2.id');
$query = $builder->get();
foreach ($query->getResult() as $row)
{
    $users[]= $row;
}
echo view('myPage', array('users' => $users) );
```

This is the most basic rudimentary intro to joins. I encourage you to [learn more about them](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the resources, but I still have a dummy question.

Basically, in my controller I return my view with $data, which includes every row in the table. How would I get the results from this joined table? Should I put this in my model or controller?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to tranform the db query into data you can use in your view. It doesn't matter if you do this in controller or model, but for sake of ease just use the controller now and move to the model after you get that working (generally database stuff happens in model but there is no rule about it)